# Ternary Expression within Ternary Expression JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inline, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I am setting background colors to all cells in a table. Within the table there is only numeric data. The code below works. It sets the background of numbers bigger then 10 to green and lower or equal to 10 to red.

```
.css({'background-color': value > 10 ? 'green' : 'red'})
```

But when to want set three different colors as background I do not know how to put it in JavaScript properly. I want a ternary expression within a ternary expression. The code below should be close to the solution. I want to set the background of numbers bigger then 10 to green and lower then 5 to red. The numbers between 5 and 10 should be getting an orange background.

```
.css({'background-color': value > 10 ? 'green' : 'background-color' : value < 5 ? 'red' : 'orange'})
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Why do you repeat `{'background-color':`…`}` in the inner ternary expression? Don’t do that.

Comment: The right term is `ternary` operator. Unlike `if-else` statements the ternary operator is an expression, which can be used inside function argument lists or object/array literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use parenthesis if you have nested *inline if*:

```
.css({'background-color': (value > 10 ? 'green' : (value < 5 ? 'red' : 'orange'))})
```

You should refactor your code into another function to avoid if-else hell, and keep your code cleaner:

```
function valueToColor(value) {
  if(value > 10) return 'green';
  if(value >= 5) return 'orange';
  return 'red';
  // equivalent to: return (value > 10 ? 'green' : (value < 5 ? 'red' : 'orange'))
}

// ...

.css({'background-color': valueToColor(value)})
```

Comment: `inline` please :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to pull out that code with a variable. It does not work because you are not grouping the ternary conditional statements and the repeated `{background-color}` key.

**This works:**

```
var variable = (value >10 ? 'green' : (value <5 ? 'red' :'orange' ));
.css({'background-color': variable})
```

**Try it:**

```js
function alertit(value) {
    var variable = (value >10 ? 'green' : (value <5 ? 'red' :'orange' ));
    alert(variable);
}

alertit(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value)
```

```html
Change value: <input type="text" value="3" onchange="alertit(this.value)">
```